# Laravel Make:Auth con SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, laravel

Buenas, estoy usando Laravel 5.2.* con PHP 5.6+, Todo va funcionando como debe ser en cuando al tema de las conexiones, use el `Make:auth` para crear el login con Laravel, pero a la hora de registrarme (o bien usar el register por defecto) me da un error:

**Mensaje de error:**

> [1/2] SQLSTATE[22007]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL
>   Server]La conversión del tipo de datos nvarchar en datetime produjo un
>   valor fuera de intervalo.
>
> [2/2] QueryException in Connection.php line 729: SQLSTATE[22007]:
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]La conversión
>   del tipo de datos nvarchar en datetime produjo un valor fuera de
>   intervalo. (SQL: insert into [users] ([name], [email], [password],
>   [updated_at], [created_at]) values (pruebaname, emailname@name.com,
>   y$f3MSrI4.mgOu3ApY5jcQIeIG85Zj1SfGVGeG/5mGBovY5bNA1LrLe, 2017-02-23 
>   10:38:54.000, 2017-02-23 10:38:54.000))

Entiendo que el error dado se debe al formato de fecha entre lo que envia Laravel y lo que recibe SQL SERVER, pero lo extraño es que al hacer el comando insert into desde new query, me da el mismo error, pero al insertar los datos directamente en la tabla, funciona... como pudiera hacer para que:

1- Laravel envie datos acorde a SQL

ó

2- El campo de la tabla de adapte para recibir bien los datos.

Comment: ¿El problema son los 3 ceros del final?

Comment: No, el problema realmente es al momento de insertar las dos fechas al SQL.

Comment: La verdad no uso SQL server entonces no sé que pueda haber de distinto, generalmente uso Postgres. Tal vez esto te pueda servir: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36451179/datetime-issue-with-laravel-5-2-ms-sql-server

Comment: Gracias, ya lo había visto, pero no hallo como aplicarlo a Laravel

Comment: Simplemente agrega la propiedad al modelo, tal y como lo explican, tus modelos normalmente extienden `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` y dicha clase contiene la propiedad `$dateFormat`: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L151

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tal y como lo referencié en mi comentario, puedes cambiar el formato de la fecha por medio de la propiedad `$dateFormat` en el modelo:

```
class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The storage format of the model's date columns.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $dateFormat = 'M j Y h:i:s'; // o el formato que te sirva

    // ....
}
```

Comment: Si no me equivoco, cuanto tu usas `make:auth` en Laravel 5.2.* el modelo del auth no te lo coloca en la carpeta **models** por defecto, donde mas lo podría colocar entonces o donde encuentro el modelo del auth cuando aplicas dicho comando (`make:auth`)?

Comment: El modelo que utiliza la autenticación en Laravel es `User`. La autenticación es un proceso, por eso solo tiene controladores y vistas, el modelo implicado es el usuario.

Comment: ¿Te refieres al archivo User.php? Lo siento soy algo nuevo en Laravel, trabaje todo esto con Mysql y no me dio ningún problema, pero con SQL cambio un poco.

Comment: Sí, el archivo User.php, el cual Laravel pone inicialmente en app/

Comment: en el tengo lo siguiente (http://imgur.com/jwqEvjW)

Comment: Sí, ahí mismo, simplemente agrega la propiedad tal y como está en la respuesta, ignora como planteo la definición de la clase.

Comment: a la perfección. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

El manejo de valores tipo fecha, siempre es algo molesto cuando uno desarrolla debido a los distintos formatos culturales que existen.

Lo primero que te recomiendo es asegurarte que el tipo de dato que vas a enviar a SQL sea un `datetime` no un `string` con formato de fecha.

Ahora bien si lo que vas a mandar a SQL es un `string` con formato de fecha, entonces utiliza siempre el siguiente formato `'YYYYMMMDD hh:mm:ss'` este nunca te va a fallar, para tu ejemplo:

- No envíes esto: `'2017-02-23 10:38:54.000'`
- Envia esto: `'20170223 10:38:54'`

A manera de ensayo simplemente pon directamente en tú código el ejemplo que te estoy dando y con seguridad no te va a presentar el error que estas indicando.

Comment: El ejemplo `'20170223 10:38:54'` Funciona perfectamente, pero ahora, como hacer para que Laravel lo envie así?